# Callback function is not working - Codeigniter3 HMVC

Tags: codeigniter-3

m getting form validation error while using callback function in HMVC CI...i didn't understant the problme...my validation code is -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_IsEmail_exist');

function IsEmail_exist() {
        $existing_email = $this->db->where("email", $this->input->post('username'))->get('tbl_user')->num_rows();//p($existing_email);echo $this->db->last_query();die;
        if ($existing_email != "0") {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Email ID already Exist.');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The following code is in Custom_Form_validation.php:

```
/* custom function by Pikachu */

class Custom_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public $CI;

    function run($module = '', $group = '') {
        (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }

}
```

and in my controller:

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library(array('Custom_Form_validation'));
        $this->form_validation->CI =& $this;
        $this->load->model('custom_model', 'custom');
    }
```

still getting "email is required" error msg in view form. Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @pikachu instead of doing this -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_IsEmail_exist');
```

use the piped elements separate into individual parameters like -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Email', 'required', 'callback_IsEmail_exist');
```

this may be help you.